# Unable to link library in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have tried to link osabstraction library in `target_link_libraries` and also added path in in `target_include_directories`

Getting error like:

> cannot find -losabstraction

Can you please suggest me how to link library from different projects .

Comment: We will need some more information to answer this question. Could you please provide [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your CMake code?

Comment: target_include_directories is irrelevant to the linker.

Comment: Seems like you used the `target_include_directories` command when you should have used the `target_link_directories` command

Comment: In target_link_directories we can give source file path or .so path?